# Java convert JFIF file to JPG file

Tags: java, type-conversion, byte, jpeg, jfif

Is there a way to convert a .JFIF file to a .jpeg file without using any online tools? I want to do this in java. The problem is that I receive files as a JFIF file. I want to create a base64 string from that, but using that string will not display any images.

Comment: JFIF is an JPEG file.

Comment: I know that I can open it in internet explorer without any problems. The problem is that when I create a base 64 string from it and set it as the source of an image it does not load.

Comment: That because you need something to convert it from base64 back to JPEG.

Comment: Should the HTML code work for a JPEG file, the same code should probably work for JFIF; you might give it mime type _application/jpeg_.

Comment: Did you get the answer for this?